# Geocoding API: house number precision for Europe (Germany/Austria), other than google?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, commercial

I am looking for an affordable geocoding option with the following criteria:

- commercial use
- <500$/month
- allows to store LatLng results in my DB
- house Number precision for Austria and Germany

The only options with sufficient coverage seem to be BING and Google.
I have already received a quote from google for $11000/year for their cheapest commercial license and it would still not allow me to store the results.

Most other options that I am aware of are either not suitable for my area (e.g. mapquest) or are based on OSM which also lacks many house numbers where I need them.

It seems that I am pretty much out of luck and now i understand why google charges such ridiculous licensing fees... because they can.

Comment: Mapbox Enterprise? No idea on the cost. They say that Austria released their addresses last July with a permissive license.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I already contacted mapbox. They charge $2.5/1000 geocodes (if you want to store them).. and a minimum amount of 10.000.000/year --> $25000/year

Comment: Don't know the cost but how about the Deutsche Post for Germany: https://www.deutschepost.de/en/d/deutsche-post-direkt/datafactory.html#build Another option could be (without knowing prices) HERE (https://company.here.com/here/)

Comment: At least for Austria you can store everything in your own DB (as @mkennedy already mentioned). Have a look at http://www.bev.gv.at/portal/page?_pageid=713,2573888&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL and https://github.com/BergWerkGIS/convert-bev-address-data

Comment: @Chris mapbox - is it solely for slightly processed OSM data?

Comment: I don't actually know what you mean by `house Number precision for Austria and Germany`.  Do mean the product will have house numbers for Austria and Germany and those house numbers will be accurate enough for you to identify the house on a map?